# How to Binding ListBox selected item and TextBox?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have listBox and i want to see the selected item ftom the listBox on some textBox.

(the Collection is a list of string)

I trying to write the code but this is not working.

```
  <ListBox x:Name="Collection__" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="Collection name:"/>
            <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding ElementName=Collection__, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

found it ...

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="ElementListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" 
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Elements/Name}"/>
</StackPanel>
```